# Draggable helper -> drop clone at position of mouseup -> draggable clone

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, user-interface

I want to create an interface similar to a wireframing or visio type app.  For example on the side of the window I would a toolbox which will have shapes, images etc which I can drag onto the main canvas.

In the case of JQuery UI the shapes in the toolbox will be helpers.  Once I drag the object onto the canvas, it needs to drop at the position where I release the mouse button.  After doing this I can still drag the clone around freely.

Can't figure out how to do this.  Here is my code ...

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#container").droppable(
            {
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).append($(ui.draggable).clone());
    }
}
        );
    $( ".draggable" ).draggable({ 
            containment: "window", 
            stack: ".draggable", 
            helper: "clone",
            revert: "invalid"   

        });

    });
```

so this will currently drop into the #container div however each clone will automatically stack down the left side.  I can no longer drag the clone afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a starting point: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rusln/MZLvN/)

but this is a very general solution, so in case you have a more specific use case let me know !

.js

```
$("#container").droppable({
  // accept draggables only from #toolbox,
  // this will prevent cloning of the draggables(inside drop event handler),
  //  that already have been dropped inside #container
  accept: "#toolbox .draggable",
  drop: function (event, ui) {
      // when a draggable is dropped: 
      // 1: clone it's helper 
      // 2: Make the helper draggable
      // 3: set containment to #container
      $(this).append($(ui.helper).clone().draggable({
          containment: "parent"
      }));
  }
});
$(".draggable").draggable({
  revert: "invalid",
  helper: "clone"
});
```

.html

```
<div id="toolbox">
<div class="draggable">drag</div>
<div class="draggable">drag</div>
<div class="draggable">drag</div>
<div class="draggable">drag</div>
</div>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Excellent! Thats certainly a good start. However if I start dragging an object in the droppable area, it clones again.

Comment: Looks like thats it :) But just trying to figure out what you had done. What is 'console.dir(ui);'? and why do you now need to add #toolbox to 'accept'?

Comment: oh, [console.dir](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console.dir) is for console logging inside dev tools.I'll update my post with  comments.